# How can I scrape file names and create directories for each filename in Python?

Tags: python, directory

I'm trying to scrape filenames inside a folder and then make directories for each filename inside another folder. This is what I've got so far but when I run it, it doesn't create the new folders in the destination folder. When I run it in the terminal it doesn't return any errors.

```
import os
import shutil

folder = "/home/ro/Downloads/uglybettyfanfiction.net/"
destination = "/home/ro/A Python Scripts/dest_test/"

# get each files path name

def ensure_dir(f):
    d = os.path.dirname(f)
    if not os.path.exists(d):
        os.makedirs(d)

for files in os.listdir(folder):
    new_path = folder + files
    ensure_dir(new_path)
```

Comment: why don't you debug or print what's happening?

Comment: Won't `d` always be the same value as `folder`, which will either exist or not. If it doesn't `ensure_dir` will never be called. Why don't you use `destination`?

Comment: That's why I made a for loop that makes a new file path on each loop with the file name changing at the end of each path, so in theory i should get folders named after the file names in the 'dest_test' folder.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few mistakes. No need to use `dirname` and you should write to your `destination`, not the same `folder`:

```
def ensure_dir(f):
    if not os.path.exists(f):
        os.mkdir(f)

for files in os.listdir(folder):
    new_path = destination + files
    ensure_dir(new_path)
```